# use android intent to display an image from internet

Tags: android

I have an image located at: http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/8c9772a0jw1dm10273empj.jpg

I want use android gallery app to view the image, so I use below code but looks like it just can't start the desired activity.

The variable pic is a string containing above image URL.

Below is code:

```
    image_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pic), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }});
```

Stack:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException)) 
    Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(int, Object) line: 1408    
    Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Context, IBinder, IBinder, Activity, Intent, int) line: 1378  
    ViewMessage(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 2833    
    ViewMessage(Activity).startActivity(Intent) line: 2939  
    ViewMessage$2.onClick(View) line: 92    
    ImageView(View).performClick() line: 2408   
    View$PerformClick.run() line: 8816  
    ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4673    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 858  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 616 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Define "it just can't start the desired activity". Does it crash, give an error, blow up? Also remember if you are accessing the internet you need INTERNET permissions.

Comment: should i define the activity in the manifest file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the manifest for the Gallery application, it does not seem to accept a URL for an image as part of the Intent.  You will have to download the image first, and then create the Intent to display the image from the file system.

Your Intent would be something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addCategory(android.content.Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pathToImageFile), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Where `pathToImageFile` is a string that has location which starts with `file:///sdcard/`